# Double integral inequality proof

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Prove that $$\iint_D \sin^2(x+y)\, dA \le \iint_D \sin(x+y)\,  dA$$ where $D= \{(x,y)\, |\, 0\le x+y\le \pi, 0\le y\le \pi\}$.

I really don't know where to begin with this problem. I'm not sure if I should use change of coordinates to polar or anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\sin^2 (x+y) \leq \sin (x+y)$, since $0 \leq \sin (x+y) \leq 1$.

Comment: but how can I use that to show the double integral section?

Comment: I need to use the D section somehow

Comment: The inequality is true on $D$.

Comment: I know I can state that sin^2(x+y<=sin(x+y) on D, but can I just say because of this that it's also true on D for the double integral? There's no additional steps? seems too easy.

Comment: It is only true on $D$, and may not be true in other regions.

Comment: But because it's true on D does that mean its true for the double integral?

Comment: Yes, it is true for the double integral.